# How to read systemd-analyze plot?

Tags: boot, 20.04, bluetooth, plymouth

I'm trying to diagnose a slow-boot-after-update in 20.04.1. I've run systemd-analyze plot (output attached), but I'm not sure how to interpret the output and figure out what is causing the delay.

[image]

The same is true of systemd-analyze critical-chain and systemd-analyze blame. How do I interpret their output to determine what is holding things up? In critical-chain, am I looking for things that take a long time to start (+), or things that became active (@) a long time after the previous thing, or something else? In blame, is it just things (other than plymouth-quit-wait.service) that take a long time? Or is it more complicated than that?

```
~$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
graphical.target @21.564s
└─multi-user.target @21.564s
  └─systemd-logind.service @879ms +384ms
    └─basic.target @812ms
      └─paths.target @812ms
        └─cups.path @810ms
          └─sysinit.target @807ms
            └─systemd-timesyncd.service @712ms +95ms
              └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @690ms +19ms
                └─systemd-journal-flush.service @305ms +384ms
                  └─systemd-journald.service @235ms +68ms
                    └─systemd-journald.socket @232ms
                      └─-.mount @230ms
                        └─system.slice @230ms
                          └─-.slice @230ms


~$ systemd-analyze blame
20.555s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                                               
  384ms systemd-journal-flush.service                                                            
  384ms systemd-logind.service                                                                   
  359ms dev-mapper-vgubuntu\x2droot.device                                                       
  271ms apport-autoreport.service                                                                
  218ms accounts-daemon.service                                                                  
  215ms upower.service                                                                           
  199ms udisks2.service                                                                          
  178ms networkd-dispatcher.service                                                              
  172ms systemd-resolved.service                                                                 
  134ms apparmor.service                                                                         
  128ms bolt.service                                                                             
  122ms lvm2-pvscan@253:0.service                                                                
  107ms bluetooth.service                                                                        
  106ms polkit.service                                                                           
  103ms NetworkManager.service                                                                   
  101ms virtualbox.service                                                                       
   99ms systemd-rfkill.service                                                                   
   95ms systemd-timesyncd.service                                                                
   90ms ModemManager.service                                                                     
   86ms user@1000.service                                                                        
   85ms lvm2-monitor.service                                                                     
   78ms switcheroo-control.service                                                               
   75ms gpu-manager.service                                                                      
   73ms thermald.service                                                                         
   71ms wpa_supplicant.service                                                                   
   68ms systemd-journald.service                                                                 
   66ms colord.service                                                                           
   64ms rtkit-daemon.service                                                                     
   61ms apport.service                                                                           
   58ms e2scrub_reap.service                                                                     
   57ms dev-mapper-vgubuntu\x2dswap_1.swap                                                       
   56ms lm-sensors.service                                                                       
   55ms systemd-udev-trigger.service                                                             
   54ms systemd-udevd.service                                                                    
lines 1-35...skipping...
```

plymouth-quit-wait.service starts, followed by a dozen or so things within a second, ending with upower.service. Then there's a ~3 sec delay to packagekit.service, followed by a ~5 second delay to two bluetooth devices, followed by an ~11 sec delay to the GUI. How do I determine which of these processes is doing something (or waiting for something else) in a way that is causing a delay?

Critical chain for plymouth-quit-wait.service (subsequent, but similar, boot):

```
~$ systemd-analyze critical-chain plymouth-quit-wait.service
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

plymouth-quit-wait.service +20.305s
└─systemd-user-sessions.service @1.090s +19ms
  └─network.target @1.079s
    └─NetworkManager.service @931ms +147ms
      └─dbus.service @929ms
        └─basic.target @894ms
          └─sockets.target @894ms
            └─uuidd.socket @894ms
              └─sysinit.target @885ms
                └─systemd-timesyncd.service @812ms +70ms
                  └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @791ms +16ms
                    └─systemd-journal-flush.service @339ms +451ms
                      └─systemd-journald.service @254ms +83ms
                        └─systemd-journald.socket @251ms
                          └─system.slice @249ms
                            └─-.slice @249ms
```

I'm focusing on this part of the plot because it's the delay from the plymouth splash screen to GUI that is new. Before the updates, the splash screen showed for a few seconds, then it went to GUI within a second. Now, the splash screen shows for a few seconds, then the screen goes black and there is a 15-20 sec delay before the GUI appears.

FYI, the updates included an update from kernel 5.8.0-43 to 5.8.0-44, as well as a number of other things. I don't believe the kernel is the problem, since rolling it back didn't fix it. Also, turning off bluebooth does not fix it.

Comment: @user535733 there seems to be a typo in `systemd-analyze blame`.

Comment: Thanks... I find I have the same problem with critical-chain and blame (added to the original post, above). How do I read this output in order to determine what's holding things up?

Comment: Still wrestling with this trying to understand what I'm looking at. In critical-chain, everything up to systemd-login.service starts in ~1 sec. The next thing after that is multi-user.target, which takes 21.564 sec. How do I go about figuring out what the delay is between systemd-login.service and multi-user.target? @user535733 any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @user535733 Thank you! Output posted above. My understanding of plymouth-quit-wait.service is that it just waits for other things then quits. But if I'm reading it correctly, critical chain shows that all of its dependencies are started within ~1 sec, but plymouth-quit-wait.service still takes ~20 sec to start. Does this imply that there is a failed process that is holding things up that does not get recorded in the critical-chain? If so, how does one look for that failed process?